# Custom animation angular material tabs

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have a problem
I'm using Angular Material tabs (https://material.angular.io/components/tabs)

I have several effects by default, the "slide" effect which changes the content and another the black effect behind my tab.I was able to remove the "slide" effect but I don't know how to modify / remove the black effect ???

[black effect 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REeIF.png)

[black effect 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNSYh.png)

Someone can help me ?

my html :

```
<mat-tab-group class="navBar" [@.disabled]="true">
<mat-tab label="all">
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
        <div (mouseover)="iconAllOn=true" (mouseout)="iconAllOn=false">
            <img class="logoNavBar" *ngIf="!iconAllOn" [src]="cheminImageAllOff">
            <img class="logoNavBar" *ngIf="iconAllOn"[src]="cheminImageAllOn">
        </div>
    </ng-template> 
    Content 1
</mat-tab>
```

Answer (score 0):

That black effect is the Material Ripple effect.

The effect works by adding a new div to your structure:

[image]

You can remove it by either targeting the element with CSS or by making use of the `disableRipple` input parameter of `MatTabNav` component (take a look [here](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api#MatTabNav)) or `MatTabGroup` ([here](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api#MatTabGroup))

Comment: Thanks a lot ! it's ok for me